# Detached Head with Branch fully merged?

Tags: git, android-studio

I am using GIT with Android Studio (means: I typially execute GIT from the UI and rely on Android Studio instead of using the command line). Now and then Android Studio gets into a detached head state for no reason as it looks to me.

I have my "HEAD", "master" and "origin/master" at the same commit. When I do a "compare" I get the result "Branch origin/master is fully merged into local "149c716" and vice versa.

When I try to merge the remote branch into the current, I get "Already up-to-date".

But when I make local changes and try to commit them to remote, I get a warning about "Detached Head".

What I did: I checked out a previous commit, compiled it to get the executables, then checked out the msot recent commit again without doing any changes.

I know there are posts about how to reconceile a detached head, but to me it looks as if I don't even have any.

[image]

--

I found this in the log, so it looks like a build file has not properly been excluded. And I think it happened because "build/*" was specified in gitignore, instead of "build/". Can I ignore the build file somehow or force a checkout which overwrites everything local? When I call "merge" it tells me there is nothing to merge.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    build/intermediates/dex-cache/cache.xml
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Comment: "then checked out the mist recent commit again without doing any changes"  Are you sure this succeeded?

Comment: anytime you type `git checkout COMMIT_SHA` you will go into detached head.  If you wanted to stay on a branch you would have instead done `git reset --hard COMMIT_SHA` to point your current branch to a different commit.

Comment: Android Studio did not say anything different. I compared the code and there aren't any differences.

Comment: @AndrewC I did not use the CLI and I don't know what Android Studio sends to GIT. I only remember I right clicked "checkout" before on older commits and could go back and forth without running into any issues, as long as I did not do any code changes. What would happen if I used `git reset --hard COMMIT_SHA` now?

Comment: `git reset --hard` is one of the few commands that is not working directory safe.  If you are currently detached you would want to do `git checkout master` I think.  In the future to switch between commits you would use `reset` instead of checkout.  I don't use Android Studio so I am guessing as to what some of the commands do in Git terms.

Comment: I just added something that I found in the log. Also, I found what Android Studio does is a simple checkout: `git checkout 149c716e6f5341b7345092d38b7aa1799fe7b744`

Comment: `git checkout master` executed directly in GIT worked, thanks @AndrewC [post this as the response so I can mark it as correct].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear how Android studio is behaving but normally

```
git checkout SHA
```

Will always move you into detached head state.

If you are checked out to a branch, and want to make your copy of that branch point to a different commit you would use

```
git reset --hard SHA
```

Note that hard reset is not working directory safe.

If you are in detached head state you can get back out of it by typing

```
git checkout BRANCH
```